# Node-Webkit: Run application on download complete

Tags: node.js, exe, auto-update, node-webkit

I have created a `Node-Webkit` application and I am trying to implement application `auto-update`.

What I have done till now is:

1. I am checking version of my application's package.json with the package.json from server.
2. If they are different, I will download the new .exe from server.
3. It's downloaded to user-folder\AppData\Local\Temp\ folder

Now I want to close the application which is open and run the new exe file. But I want to do it pragmatically. Can anyone help me in doing this? Is there a way to open application when it's path is specified?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spawn` from the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) API.

Spawn the new exe, detach it and unreference it, then close the current app.

Something like:

```
require("child_process").spawn('path/to/new/exe', [], {detached: true}).unref();
require('nw.gui').Window.get().close(true);
```